# How can I combine the latest result from my HttpClient and FormControl.valueChanges to apply a filter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, combinelatest

I have a component where I am using a service to fetch data that also has a search filter

I would like the Observable to be the end result of the HttpClient with the filter applied from the FormControl `searchControl` so that `reportPeriods$` is a stream of the filtered result

This works but I am noticing that my map function is firing N times for each item that exists in `ReportPeriod[]` and I am not sure this is the correct usage

The request to fetch `getReportPeriods(12)` should only fire once

```
export class ReportPeriodComponent {
    reportPeriods$: Observable<ReportPeriod[]>;
    searchControl = new FormControl<string>('');
    private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

    constructor(public qaService: QaService, private reportPeriodService: ReportPeriodService) {
        this.reportPeriods$ = combineLatest({
            reportPeriods: this.reportPeriodService.getReportPeriods(12),
            text: this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''))
        }).pipe(
            takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
            map(({ reportPeriods, text }) => {
                if (text && text.length > 0) {
                    return reportPeriods.filter((reportPeriod) => reportPeriod.friendlyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                } else {
                    return reportPeriods;
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

ReportPeriodService

```
getReportPeriods(monthsAgo: number): Observable<ReportPeriod[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('monthsAgo', monthsAgo);

    return this.http.get<ReportPeriod[]>(`${this.url}/report-periods`, { params }).pipe(
        map((reportPeriods) => {
            return reportPeriods
                .map((reportPeriod) => {
                    return {
                        ...reportPeriod,
                        startDate: new Date(reportPeriod.startDate),
                        endDate: new Date(reportPeriod.endDate)
                    };
                })
                .sort((a, b) => b.endDate.getTime() - a.endDate.getTime());
        })
    );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know that `map` fires once for each item? I created a small app with similar logic and it runs as expected. Can you reproduce with a small app on Stackblitz?

Comment: With the breakpoint set, I can keep continuing and see the same data coming through in the map. distinctUntilChanged() seems to have no effect and the number of times the map fires directly relates to the count of the array of ReportPeriod[]

Comment: I assume that the api is called only once. In the service, replace the api call with static data for testing. If `map` runs only once then you know the problem is in the service method.

Comment: You are most certainly correct Benny, part of the issue is that I was referencing the observable in my template with an | async operator in my nested *ngFor forgetting that async operator is equivalent to calling .subscribe with the benefit of not having to manage that subscription (Monday problems) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

switchMap is the perfect operator to solve something like this, I will also say  the reason for the observable appearing to fire duplicate times if because I was also referencing that observable with an async pipe in the *ngFor of my template

```
    this.reportPeriods$ = this.reportPeriodService
        .getReportPeriods(12)
        .pipe(tap((reportPeriods) => this.qaService.selectedReportPeriod.set(reportPeriods[0])))
        .pipe(
            takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
            switchMap((reportPeriods) => {
                return this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
                    startWith(''),
                    map((text: string | null) => {
                        if (text && text.length > 0) {
                            return reportPeriods.filter((reportPeriod) => reportPeriod.friendlyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                        } else {
                            return reportPeriods;
                        }
                    })
                );
            })
        );
```